# issue getting image in div using ajax : update for new issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jqgrid

Guys now I am able to get image in my webpage however the the bottom of the image is messed up. I am encoding bytearray as a string and sending it to ajax. In webpage the image is appearing what it supposed to be but at the bootm of the image few elemets of the pic are showing up twice. I don't know why ajax is showing messed up image , any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
function pieChart(){

var param= new FormData();
fd.append("file", $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
            url: '/test.html',
            data: inputfl,
            cache: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            datatyp:'text',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result){
                      $("#testimage").attr("src", 'data:image/png;base64,'+result);
                
            }
        });


}
```

```html
<div id="pie">
<img src="" id="testimage"></img>
</div>



<!--in mvc this is what I am doing to encode bytearray-->
ByteArrayOutputStream op= new ....();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", op);
byte [] test= op.toByteArray();

res.setHeader("..");
.....
.....

byte [] test1 = Base64.encode(data);
resOutputStream().write(test1).flush();



<!--when i inspect this is what i am getiing in src tag -->
 src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```